# The grid of chart doesn't show right

Tags: android, achartengine

i got a problem when rotate the device, it relates to the show grid in achartengine, when i put the device in LANSCAPE, the bar will view like this:

http://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3NUAgD0tB0YLVpPV2pab05GZDA/edit

But when POTRAIT, the bar show like this:

http://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3NUAgD0tB0YRG5tX1c3MElXZTg/edit

I don't know where to fix the problem with that grid, because when i rotate the device, i just need to intiate the chart with new orientation. Could you help me to solve the grid problem?

Thanks

Clark

Comment: You should re-init or re-draw your chart in `onConfigurationChanged`

Comment: Yes, i create the chart in the onCreate(), so when we rotate the device, the chart will auto re-init, i just need to check the orientation to init the chart.

Any help, please

Answer (score 0):

After you reinitialize the chart, please call a `repaint();`

```
mChartView.repaint();
```

If this doesn't fix the issue then it means it is one of the known problems with the vertical orientation for bar charts in AChartEngine, see [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=203).

Comment: Actually, i called the repaint(). In the initiate function, i detect if the device was in LANSCAPE, i set the orientatin to "Oientation.HORIZONTAL", and when the device in the PORTRAIT, i will set the orientation to "Orientation.VERTICAL". It will have above the problem. If i change the LANSCAPE with VERTICAL, and PORTRAIT with HORIZONTAL, it works fine. I don't know what problem is that? Could you give me more advice?